# Ant- How can i compare the list of strings?

Tags: ant

```
 <target name="build">
 <for list="${platform}" param="platform" trim="true">
 <sequential>
 <if>
 <equals arg1="${platform}" arg2="${project.SuppoortedPlatforms}" />
 <then>
 <antcall target="package.${platform}" />
 </then>
 </if>
 </sequential>
 </for>
 </target>
```

where i'm getting platfrom values at runtime (eg:windows,ios) and project.SuppoortedPlatforms is declared under build.properties (eg:android,ios). how can i compare the list of strings? 
could anyone help me to solve this problem?

Thanks,
sandhiya

Answer (score 1):

You are looping over a comma-separated list of platforms, and for each one you're checking if it is contained in the list of supported platforms in `project.SuppoortedPlatforms`. This should go like this:

```
<for list="${platform}" param="platformParam" trim="true">
    <sequential>
    <if>
       <contains string="${project.SuppoortedPlatforms}" substring="@{platformParam}" />
        <then>
          <antcall target="package.@{platformParam}" />
        </then>
      </if>
       </sequential>
     </for>
```

The parameter in the loop should be accessed with `@` instead of `$`. Also it would be better to rename the parameter for readability (`platformParam` instead of `platform`).

Comment: If the answer worked, accept the answer. Possibly with an upvote.  See the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

```
  Instead of using contains task, i myself tried with the nested for loop, its cool working fine. 


  <for list="${platforms}" param="platformparam" trim="true">
 <sequential>
    <for list="${project.SupportedPlatforms}" param="supplatformparam" trim="true">
    <sequential>
        <if>
        <equals arg1="@{platformparam}" arg2="@{supplatformparam}" />
        <then>
            <antcall target="package.@{platformParam}" />
        </then>
        </if>
    </sequential>
    </for>
</sequential>
</for>
```